# angular order with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

as I understand this link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/k5fHMU?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log ($scope.name);
});

app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>',
    controller: function($scope, $element){
    $scope.name = $scope.name + "Second ";
    }
  }
})
```

first angular look at the app controller, then at the directive controller, and the app controller not know the vars of the directive controller. how can I use variables of the directive controller in the app controller?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is what you want](http://plnkr.co/edit/ivkPu8?p=preview)
.

I did this on Basis of your Plunker Code.

The thing which you want can be achieved using Angular Events($broadCast & $emit i.e. Controller to Controller communication using angular.)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
//exactly gets called after event has been emitted by child controller
  $scope.$on('SecondRun', function(event, data){
    console.log($scope.name);
     $scope.name =  $scope.name + 'First ';
  });
});

app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>',
    controller: function($scope, $element){
      $scope.name = "Second ";
      //emiting event to parent scopes
      $scope.$emit('SecondRun',true);
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
      scope.name = scope.name + "Third ";
    }
  }
})
```

Hopefully This will help you.

Comment: why the scope of the directive controller is child scope? I saw that by default directives use their parent scope. thanks

Comment: yes, you're correct.parent scope concept will be there if i use isolated scope. I've updated the plunkr..Thanks :)